# Automatically add line item(s) to a vendor bill in suitescript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

I'm new to Suitescript 2.0, so I hope I can get some help from a more experienced developer over here.

I want to create a new Vendor Bill in Netsuite. I have data available that I want to use to populate certain fields in this screen. The populating of the header fields is not an issue, but I'm having problems to automatically add (existing) items to the Vendor Bill when/before the page loads using Suitescript 2.0.

I receive the error "Please choose an item to add" all the time.

Does anybody have a suggestion how I can solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, @R.W. Blok it would be useful if you include the code you are currently using. However but the error you are getting my guess is that you are missing the item id at the line level.

Comment: Hi Emerson, the following code results in the error I mentioned before although the vlaue of 24 is of an existing item.

Comment: function pageInit(context) {
 var vendorBill = context.currentRecord;
   
 vendorBill.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
                  
    vendorBill.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
  fieldId: 'item',
  value: '24',
  forceSyncSourcing : true
 });
                  
   vendorBill.commitLine({
    sublistId: 'item'
    });
}

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from '24'. I did a quick test and your code worked for me, even with the single quotes, try with another item as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Client Script on the creation of vendor bill and add item of your choice in `pageInit` event using following code.

```
function pageInit(context) {
   var currRecord = currenctRecord.get();
   currRecord.selectNewLine({sublistId: 'item' });
   currRecord.setCurrentSublistText({
       sublistId: 'item',
       fieldId: 'item'
       text: <<your item name>>
       forceSyncSourcing: true
   });
}
```

Comment: Hi Viks, my code is almost the same as the code you provided, but I got the error mentioned earlier although I am "selecting" an existing item in my code.